# vertical and horizontal centering multiple DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have two `div.slides` inside a `div.modal`. I want to position them vertically and horizontally using `translateX` and `translateY` approach, so they would be both centered and one above / behind the other. The problem is that my current code will draw them one after the other:

[image: the problem]

How can I make them so they will be both in center (one behind the other) ?

Here's the CSS code:

```
.oa-modal {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 320px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
}

.oa-slides {
    position: relative;
}
.oa-slide {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.oa-slide-1 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.oa-slide-2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="oa-modal">

    <div class="oa-slides">
        <div class="oa-slide oa-slide-1">
            slide 1
        </div>

        <div class="oa-slide oa-slide-2">
            <p>slide</p>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is also a JSFiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9qmdyuj0/

Comment: Do you mean you want to make it look like 3D?

Comment: No, I just want them both to be centered at the same point.

Comment: You want the red one on the top or the yellow one?

Comment: It doesn't matter.. Red or the yellow one on top..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .oa-modal {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 320px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: fixed;
    height: auto;
    }

    .oa-slide {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .oa-slide-1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border:1px solid green;
    z-index:100;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .oa-slide-2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
    border:1px solid blue;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="oa-modal">
    <div class="oa-slides">
    <div class="oa-slide oa-slide-1">
    slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="oa-slide oa-slide-2">
    <p>slide</p>
    <p>2</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please do let me know if this helps.

Thanks

Comment: The end result should look like that, but I'm looking at a solution, which is not affected by changing .oa-slide's width or height. If I do that here, I have to adjust .oa-slide-1 left and top position. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Have made some alterations to the above answer. Please try this and let me know if this works fine.